# Open a new window (Popup) javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android, popup

I am trying to develop a mobile application and I want to open a page in the form of pop up

i use this code:

```
$('#header-left-container').prepend(results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail +"" +
                    "<br>" +
                    "<a  href='#null' onclick='open_infos()'  > <img src='../js/images/add.png' > </a>" +
                    "<textarea rows='6'  cols='60'  name='"+results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail+"'> </textarea><br><br>" );


function open_infos()
 {
 window.open('../prestation_html/list_rubrique.html','nom_de_ma_popup','menubar=no, scrollbars=no, top=100, left=100, width=300, height=200');
 }
```

but it not work, it crashes the emulator on a gray page